# Does overfishing in one ocean hurt fishstock in another?

Tags: ichthyology, marine-biology, environment, ecosystem

If there's overfishing in the Atlantic or North Sea - will this affect fish stocks in the Indian ocean? Are there papers on this?

The question I'm trying to answer is whether overfishing by developed countries has an impact on developing countries fishstocks?

I could see two different scenarios:

-fishstocks are connected globally and if you overfish in one ocean biomass from other oceans will 'flow in'
- the oceans ecosystems are more or less 'disconnected' and somewhat independent of each other

I would appreciate citations if there are any.